# Trigger in mysql causing error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

What is the error in the following code. I am executing in mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_order_insert
BEFORE INSERT 
    ON `order` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `grocery`.`order_seqid` VALUE(NULL);
    SET NEW.order_id = CONCAT('#GNC', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(),3,'0'));
END;
```

Grocery is the database and order_seqid and order are 2 table.
order_seqid is a table with only 1 attribute if type int and auto increment.
Am trying to put a prefix on the id which we insert into order table.
I am getting 2 errors in `INSERT INTO.....` and `END;` line

Comment: Yes, errors. I get those too. What's important is **the specific error** you're getting. MySQL goes to great lengths to identify the exact location of a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Did you declare a delimiter before your trigger definition? Something like

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tg_order_insert
BEFORE INSERT 
    ON `order` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `grocery`.`order_seqid` VALUE(NULL);
    SET NEW.order_id = CONCAT('#GNC', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(),3,'0'));
END
//
```

Because if you don't, then MySQL thinks you're trying to end your trigger definition when it sees that first `;` and calls syntax error.

Comment: Don't forget to accept & upvote if this answer solved your problem ;)