# Whats wrong with this mysql trigger definition?

Tags: mysql

Just don't understand why it's throwing this error:

*ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1*

Trigger definition as below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `aaa` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `aaa_table`  
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (`NEW.field1` LIKE 'ABC-%')  
    AND 
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `aaa_table` 
        WHERE `aaa_table.field2` = `NEW.field2` 
        AND `aaa_table.field3` = `NEW.field3`) > 0 
   THEN 
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Verify Insert Failed - record Exists!'  
   END IF; 

   IF (`NEW.field1` NOT LIKE 'ABC-%')  
    AND 
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `aaa_table` 
        WHERE `aaa_table.field2` = `NEW.field2` 
        AND `aaa_table.field4` = `NEW.field4`) > 0 
   THEN 
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Verify Insert Failed - record Exists!'  
   END IF;
END
```

Anyone can help?

also I will be happy to hear any ideas to imporve this syntax. I'm trying to verify the uniqueness of recoreds, which is based on field1 value - it its LIKE 'ABC-%' then there shoudn't be more than one row with thw same field2 & field3, otherwise then there shoudn't be more than one row with thw same field2 & field4.
tried to achieve that by virtual column, but unique key can't be defined on such a column.

**UPDATE:**

I tried @Baram suggestion:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `aaa` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `aaa_table`  
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.`field1` LIKE 'ABC-%')  
    AND 
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `aaa_table` 
        WHERE `aaa_table`.`field2` = NEW.`field2` 
        AND `aaa_table`.`field3` = NEW.`field3`) > 0 
   THEN 
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Verify Insert Failed - record Exists!';  
   END IF; 

   IF (NEW.`field1` NOT LIKE 'ABC-%')  
    AND 
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `aaa_table` 
        WHERE `aaa_table`.`field2` = NEW.`field2` 
        AND `aaa_table`.`field4` = NEW.`field4`) > 0 
   THEN 
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Verify Insert Failed - record Exists!';
   END IF;
END
```

yet keep on getting the same error. Any ideas?

thanks!

**UPDATE 2**

found the problem, hopes it would help anyone with the same problem:

I've had to add the delimiter definition, so that the query won't break into few on the semicolon.

Comment: You shouldn't have backticks around `NEW.field1`, they should just be around `field1`.

Comment: The syntax error is because you need `;` at the end of the line before `END IF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is because you forgot the `;` at the end of the statements before `END IF`.

Also, `NEW.` should not be inside the backticks, it prevents `NEW` from being processed as a special keyword. Similarly, `` `aaa_table.fieldX` `` should be `` `aaa_table`.`fieldX` ``, so that the `.` will be treated as a delimiter rather than part of the column name (although there's no real need to specify the table names in these queries, since they're only selecting from one table).

```
CREATE TRIGGER `aaa` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `aaa_table`  
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.`field1` LIKE 'ABC-%')  
    AND 
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `aaa_table` 
        WHERE `aaa_table`.`field2` = NEW.`field2` 
        AND `aaa_table`.`field3` = NEW.`field3`) > 0 
   THEN 
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Verify Insert Failed - record Exists!';  
   END IF; 

   IF (NEW.`field1` NOT LIKE 'ABC-%')  
    AND 
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `aaa_table` 
        WHERE `aaa_table`.`field2` = NEW.`field2` 
        AND `aaa_table`.`field4` = NEW.`field4`) > 0 
   THEN 
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Verify Insert Failed - record Exists!';
   END IF;
END
```

Instead of checking `COUNT(1)`, you could use an `EXISTS` query. And you can combine the two variations.

```
IF IF(NEW.field1 LIKE 'ABC-%',
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM aaa_table
            WHERE field2 = NEW.field2
            AND field3 = NEW.field3),
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM aaa_table
            WHERE field2 = NEW.field2
            AND field4 = NEW.field4)
        )
THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Verify Insert Failed - record Exists!';  
END IF;
```

Comment: tanks, i tried to add the ';' and it's throwing out: *ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12*

Comment: tried also the short if idea, as a result I get: *SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Verify Insert Failed - record Exists!'
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '' at line 19

END IF
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'END IF' at line 1

END
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'END' at line 1* what should I do? feels like something basic is missing

Comment: Do you have a `DELIMITER` statement before you define the trigger, so you can use `;` inside it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104422/trigger-in-mysql-causing-error

Comment: thats actually was the issue, please see update 2 in my question. thank you!